# UNet: InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'concatenate' (type Concatenate)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Even though the shape of both the input of the concatenation layer is same (as I've printed) there is an error showing different shapes.

```py
class UNet(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, shape=(572, 572, 1), **kwargs):
    self.concat = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1) # concats through depth
    ...

  class CONV2_BLOCK(keras.layers.Layer):
    ...      

  class CONV_T(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.conv_t = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=2, strides=2)

    def call(self, inputs):
      outputs = self.conv_t(inputs)
      return outputs

  class CROP(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, cropping, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.cropping = cropping
      self.crop = keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=self.cropping)

    def call(self, inputs):
      outputs = self.crop(inputs)
      return outputs

  def call(self, inputs):
    # self.conv_arr = [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
    # self.crop_arr = [4, 17, 40, 88] down to up

    x1 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(inputs)
    print(x1.shape)
    x = self.maxpool(x1)
    print(x.shape)
    ...

    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=1024)(x)
    print(x.shape)

    print(f"convt shape{self.CONV_T(filters=512)(x).shape}")
    print(f"crop shape{self.CROP(cropping=4)(x4).shape}")
    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=512)(x), self.CROP(cropping=4)(x4)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=512)(x)

    ...

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=64)(x), self.CROP(cropping=88)(x1)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(x)

    outputs = self.conv_sz1(x)

    return outputs
```

output of above code:

***[conv_t shape(2, 56, 56, 512),
crop shape(2, 56, 56, 512)]*** # printed

#error

`--->83 x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=216)(x), self.CROP(cropping=17)(x3)])`
    `84 x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=256)(x)`

> Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal: shape[0] = [2,104,104,216] vs. shape[1] = [2,102,102,256] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

Comment: as you can see, the shapes are different, how is keras supposed to concatenate them? one has "images" of 102x102, and the other one have 104x104

Comment: but when i print the shapes it is shows `[conv_t shape(2, 56, 56, 512), crop shape(2, 56, 56, 512)] # printed` ... same right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```py
class UNet(keras.Model):
  """
  argument: input_shape=(572, 572, 1) => default
  """
  def __init__(self, shape=(572, 572, 1), **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.shape = shape
    self.maxpool = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)
    self.concat = keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1) # concats through depth
    self.conv_sz1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=1, padding="same")

  class CONV2_BLOCK(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.filters = filters
      self.conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)
      self.batchnorm = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
      self.relu = keras.layers.Activation(keras.activations.relu)
      self.conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=3, use_bias=False)

    def call(self, inputs):
      x = self.conv1(inputs)
      x = self.batchnorm(x)
      x = self.relu(x)
      x = self.conv2(x)
      x = self.batchnorm(x)
      outputs = self.relu(x)
      return outputs


  class CONV_T(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.conv_t = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=2, strides=2)

    def call(self, inputs):
      outputs = self.conv_t(inputs)
      return outputs

  class CROP(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, cropping, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.crop = keras.layers.Cropping2D(cropping=cropping)

    def call(self, inputs):
      outputs = self.crop(inputs)
      return outputs

  def call(self, inputs):
    # self.conv_arr = [64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
    # self.crop_arr = [4, 17, 40, 88] down to up

    x1 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(inputs)
    print(x1.shape)
    x = self.maxpool(x1)
    print(x.shape)

    x2 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=128)(x)
    print(x2.shape)
    x = self.maxpool(x2)
    print(x.shape)

    x3 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=256)(x)
    print(x3.shape)
    x = self.maxpool(x3)
    print(x.shape)

    x4 = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=512)(x)
    print(x4.shape)
    x = self.maxpool(x4)
    print(x.shape)

    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=1024)(x)
    print(x.shape)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=512)(x), self.CROP(cropping=4)(x4)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=512)(x)
    
    # line edited
    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=256)(x), self.CROP(cropping=16)(x3)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=256)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=128)(x), self.CROP(cropping=40)(x2)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=128)(x)

    x = self.concat([self.CONV_T(filters=64)(x), self.CROP(cropping=88)(x1)])
    x = self.CONV2_BLOCK(filters=64)(x)

    outputs = self.conv_sz1(x)

    return outputs
```

What I've changed:

- `self.CONV_T(filters=216)(x)` to `self.CONV_T(filters=256)(x)`
- At the same line: `self.CROP(cropping=17)(x3)` to `self.CROP(cropping=16)(x3)`.

Comment: Hi(I'm 17) Luca saw your profile. I'm also interested in fields like applying ML to pure sciences. Can you explain in brief what's your field about and how you use ml in physics?

Comment: Basically, I work on deep learning models for high-energy physics. HEP studies the matter and how it interacts. I've worked on signal-background classification that aims to find a theorized particle decay, and more recently on anomaly detection with (variational) auto-encoders from images of particle collisions that basically has the same aim but with much less assumptions on the signal.

Comment: ok. And are you from cs or phy background? how did you get started in it?

Comment: I'm from CS with no physics background (at university level, at least). Consider that I learned by myself the most I know about ML/DL. Anyway, I've been dealing with HEP problems since I started my PhD (late 2020), but from a different perspective you can view physics as just an application domain. I mean ML/DL is quite general, you can apply it almost everywhere. Indeed, having knowledge about the domain (e.g. physics) allows, in principle, to combine theory with ML.

Comment: did you do masters/Msc then phd because you had no background in phy? AND Is your research MAINLY about phy or ml/dl?

Comment: I did a master's degree in CS with a focus on data science. Then, I was searching for a PhD in DL, and I ended up doing research at the physics department. This was not planned; my main research is still about ML/DL but, now, applied to physics. You know it was a bit weird at the beginning but I can tell you that physics, in particular HEP, offers a lot of opportunities for new applications and methods of ML/DL: it's growing very fast towards adopting ML and DL.

Comment: after phd are there jobs like working in a lab than in academia?

Comment: Well, there are also industry, and (big) tech companies that are involved or have some interest in developing and/or applying ML. But If you're lucky enough to get a good education, you don't need a PhD unless the company has a strict requirement on that